# vuejs click testing mouse event

Tags: vue.js, chai, vue-test-utils

i have a template with the following

```
            <button type="button" id="alogin" class="btn btn-primary btn-raised btn-block btn-lg" @click="login()">Sign In</button>
```

the login function is quite long but composed of

```
login() {
    this.error = 'none';
    this.error_message = null;
    const self = this;
    authentication.login(config, self.id_number, self.password, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {

      } else {

          self.startSession();
        }

    });
  }
```

ive try testing clicking the login button like after setting

```
it('tries to login', () => {
  LoginComponent.id_number = '293io090';
  LoginComponent.password = 'password';

expect(LoginComponent.$el.querySelector('#alogin').click()).to.equal(true);
```

but end up getting undefined. ive used  vuejs test utils to find('#alogin') but the result is still the same. getting stuck

Comment: Try remove `()` in `@click="login()"`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `mount` or `shallowMount` from `vue-test-utils` so you should know that these functions return `Wrapper` for your component and `find` method returns wrapper as well. So you can invoke click handler like this:

```
LoginComponent.find('#alogin').trigger('click')
```